# Question regarding AIBN in toluene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image: Reaction Scheme]
Hi guys, I am trying to perform bromination of this compound using AIBN as a radical initiator. However, it seems like AIBN is only sold commercially as 0.2 M in toluene.

Is it possible to use AIBN directly as it (0.2 M in toluene) is or should I try to remove the toluene first before performing this reaction? (Not sure if toluene will be brominated instead of thymidine)

Thank you!

Comment: If AIBN solid is not available, can you get the cyclohexyl analogue 1,1′-Azobis(cyclohexanecarbonitrile) (AHCN) which will do the same job?

Comment: It is always good to explain less common acronyms like [AIBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azobisisobutyronitrile) aka azobisisobutyronitrile. Even if you assumed readers able to help would know it, it frequently happens the help comes from those who are not familiar with it.

Comment: AIBN is sold by Sigma-Aldrich as a powder (98%). https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/441090

Comment: Is this your other account? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/125687/catmystery987?tab=profile

Answer (score 3):

Before AIBN was developed as a radical initiator, the world used benzoyl peroxide [example here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01172a016). If none of the AIBN family of initiators are available then you can use benzoyl peroxide under similar conditions.

Comment: Hi Waylander, thank you for the reply. May I ask, if I am able to find Azobis(cyclohexanecarbonitrile) will it be better to use this instead of benzoyl peroxide? 

And also is benzoyl peroxide compatible for use with benzene as the solvent?

Comment: If you can get one of the AIBN family, I would use that. Benzoyl peroxide is compatible with benzene.